# Is there a way to display current noise words in SQL 2000 Full Text Indexing?

Tags: sql-server-2000, full-text-search

I know this is ancient technology, but sometimes upgrading is not always an option.

Does anyone now how to list the actual noise words that are currently in use on a SQL 2000 Full Text Index?

We have a recurring problem on a very old SQL 2000 system.  It is a 3 way Windows 2003 cluster.  Once in a while the cluster fails over to a new node, and when that node comes online it seems to be using a different noise word list than what we want.

It seems that various service packs for SQL 2000 leave noise word files, and when the failover happens the first noiseword file found (in any directory) is the one that gets loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing a known issue (where the default Windows `noise.enu` file is used instead of SQL Server's version). According to [KB #889708](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889708), you need to copy the following registry key from the good node to the bad nodes:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ContentIndexCommon\LanguageResources\Override
```

Then you may still need to re-populate your FT indexes, not sure, and no 2000 instance handy to test, sorry. Also I don't believe there is any way to query the list of noise words (like you can on more modern versions).

Comment: That is what I was afraid of.